# How to kill people with blaster weapons

Tags: science-fiction, warfare, weapons, aliens

Recently, the R&D team found an exiting, yet unfortunately nonlethal weapon; Blaster technology. Blaster technology **fires a projectile that moves at the speed of light, strikes the target, and then applies up to 120,000 Newtons of force to and object up to 1860 cubic meters** directed in any direction. There was a brief moment where we could rip beings apart with the sudden G's, or have the blaster only target specific internal organs or circuitry, or rip through a section of star ship hull with a souped up, targeted version. However, all of those weaknesses in energy shielding have been cleared up, and are no longer possible. **Blasters are strictly limited to entire shielded objects. Targeting part of an unshielded object is usually too complex If an object is too big, the blaster has no effect.** However, I am not a peace officer, I am a soldier, and **I want to make sure that a being wielding a blaster is dealing just as much damage as someone wielding our other weapons.**
For reference, here are the other weapons we use. Yes, there are thrown rocks, shrapnel, and "guns", but shielding of any kind nullifies those without effort. Anything beyond what is described here is probably planet mounted, and another division's business. Also, unshielded enemies are irrelevant, as one hit from any real weapon will kill them, no matter what they are.

- ElMags are either short range electromagnetic pulses, or more commonly, attached to the edge of sharp metal like a sword. They are the most efficient weapons for destroying shields, but terribly short ranged, with effective range averaging five feet, with a maximum of twenty feet for some of the better ranged pulse weapons.
- Ray weaponry is just trowing gamma rays at your opponent until their shields break. It destroys shields even faster than ElMags, but it has a tendency to hit what you aren't aiming at, and irradiates the area after you fire, witch again, damages shields. Very fun, very messy.
- Beam weapons are the least damaging of the three, but they are very far ranged and precise, much more so than the other two, with no effective limit on range, besides planet curvature or walls or whatever. They are also very nice for destroying evidence, as they work by heating things up to 3500 degrees Celsius, turning that pesky hard drive to vapor without damaging the flooring.

With that in mind, how do we work so that blasters can stack up? these are the weapons the enemy has as well, so keep that in mind. **Our goal here is to make sure that blasters are dropping enemies.**

Thank you for your compliance,

Admiral C-445g

edit/ps:
some of you have asked for details on our shields. Shields protect any sane being on any side of the conflict, completely covering their body. the shields completely protect from any kinetic energy without wasting power. Heat, gamma radiation, and electromagnetism will be fully stopped, but will drain the the shield's "counterweight battery". Once the shield's counterweight battery fails, the shield will go from full protection to no protection. If a being is unprotected, a hit from any weapon will kill them, no matter what they are, due to the extreme levels of power we put into these weapons to damage shields.

Yes, you can damage shields with electromagnets, but it requires them to be powered by a small star to be effective, and has not worked the last three times we tried it.

Comment: 120,000 Newtons is, according to Wikipedia, the approximate force generated by a [Pratt & Whitney F100 jet engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_F100) with its afterburner engaged. I fail to see how hitting a person with that much force could possibly be nonlethal.

Comment: @F1krazy I read it that it can do *up to* 120.000 Newton and you don't hit the person, but a shield.

Comment: A shield isn't going to protect the person from being propelled backwards into (and probably through) the nearest vertical surface at hypersonic speeds, which is what will happen if you apply 120,000 Newtons to them.

Comment: huh. I hadn't considered sending someone through a wall. The shields would still protect them from the force.

Comment: @RobertSpencer But could they? Your shields would likely have to break the laws of inertia and/or thermodynamics. Protecting from a force by decelerating an incoming object is one thing. You can at least make the force field push against something in the surroundings and transfer the energy/damage to there.  But if it doesn't do that then the alternative is to turn the energy into heat which could fry the user depending on the energy involved unless it is also capable of somehow dissipating the heat instantaneously over a sufficiently wide area. [cont...]

Comment: And if it doesn't do that and the projectile has enough momentum to send the person flying then the shield either has to spread that impulse from projectile over time to the wearer so they accelerate non-lethally. Then it has to transfer the deceleration of impact with the wall to the wearer over time. In either case, if the velocity is too fast and the shield not big enough in volume to provide enough distance between the edge of the shield and the user inside then there is not enough distant to both simultaneously decelerate or accelerate over and prevent physical contact.

Comment: I'm not sure this is properly answerable without specifics of what your shield can do in regards to energy consumption, heat dissipation, how exactly it protects the target.

Answer (score 3):

**Chuck things with it**

Applying 120,000 newtons of force to a projectile of 1kg will accelerate it to 0.99c in 40 minutes accumulating 288 megajoules of energy. 3 hours=1.7gigajoules, continued application of force will continue to transfer energy.

When the projectile hits a shield it will deliver all of the accumulated energy into the shield instantaneously and at this speed the projectile will be converted into high energy charged particles at the moment of impact, which should directly compete with gamma ray weaponry but with practically unlimited range. Also note that smaller projectile size = higher energy particles. The major drawback is that due to acceleration time this can only be used against non-moving targets such as planets or installations.

If the strike is planned properly in advance then a team of blaster equipped strikecraft can deliver (squadron size x 120,000 x lead time in seconds) joules of energy to a stationary target from a safe standoff distance. This won't compete with nukes on overall power but it will deliver more energy to a single point, if you make it the right point then it will do more damage than a nuke. Nukes are nondirectional whereas this is basically a gigajoule-scale shaped charge. With sufficient strikecraft / acceleration time this type of attack can deliver a massive amount of energy into any stationary object from a safe distance.

On the point of nukes, for increased damage the projectile can be a barely subcritical mass of plutonium - with sufficient acceleration time the energy released at the moment of impact will cause it to detonate at point blank to the shield, this would increase the amount of energy delivered by orders of magnitude.

**Shove an EIMags sword into the blaster launcher**

Bish bosh, EM sword launcher.

**Use it as a grapple**

Use the blaster to drag a shielded object to within range of the short range instruments.

Comment: This is absolutely cheating and I love it. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Circumvent the enemy blaster shields, put a modulator inside**

Just order some of these beam weapons from another planet (see below).. and in the meanwhile, go for a change of plan considering your blaster. The enemy has found an effective shield against your blaster technology, so your weapon needs to be *modified*, to penetrate that shield. There are frequencies involved.. Or consider one component of your blaster be placed inside (or beamed over) in advance, before it does its work ? The device could anti modulate the enemy shield from within, seconds before you put your blaster shot. In short, I think your blaster needs to go back to the drawing board..

**Use the appropriate weapon**

Unshielded enemies are irrelevant, you say. So you want to kill (large groups of) shielded individuals. Don't try to shoot mice, your blaster is too heavy. Consider a beam weapon. High energy beam weapons could be enhanced for several purposes.. you could e.g. *blind* thousands of enemy at once, using the beam weapon, combined with rotating mirrors. Even kill them, with an accurately multiplexed beam: penetrate by pinpointing certain weak spots, e.g. take out the power supply for their personal shield and see what happens.. Helmets and cameras could also be vulnerable spots.. No human can withstand a concentrated, sustained light/EM beam that would heat things up to 3500 degrees Celcius.

Answer (score 0):

**EMP rifle grenades.**

You have two complementary weapons systems here. EM weapons are ideal shield-killers but have short range. Blasters are great at throwing things but worthless against shields. So why not combine their strengths? Dial down the output of your blasters and use them to deliver EM charges straight to the enemy's doorstep. Then, when they're vulnerable with their shields down, follow up with a volley of full-power blaster shots.

Even if your EM weapons are relatively large, the sheer power of the blaster as a delivery system means that traditional limits on the size and heft of rifle (or hand) grenades are completely irrelevant. The only limitation on how much ordnance you can throw at the enemy is how much you can carry with you.